# Error saving joined features in existing Geopackage gpkg from QGIS Model Designer

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage

I have created a Model Designer to automate a routine task. The problem comes when saving the generated data in an existing geopackage.

By joining attributes by location I generate around 10 points. These 10 points I want to insert into a gpkg that already exists.

To do this I do the following: After "join attributes by location" I use the "Keep Fields" algorithm to select the 3 joined fields that interest me. Within "Keep Fields Tool" I select pre-calculated value and write the fields that I want to be saved: 'date;cod_insp;fecha_insp'

To save (insert) this data into an existing geopackage, I select save to Database table, select my Geopackage and do not write the table name so that it does not generate a new table within the geopackage.

[image]

Once the process is done, when I open the geopackage the data from the fields has not been copied to the corresponding field, however the fields have the same name and format. If, for example, I modify the list of fields to keep ('fecha;cod_insp;fecha_insp') and add more fields, these are inserted into any other field without any logical sense.

[image]

How can I insert resulting data into an existing geopackage from Model Designer?

I find it quite illogical that there is no algorithm to "copy and paste" attributes like the option there is in the attribute table.

Comment: I think the output option Save to Database Table with algorithm keep fields (actually called Retain Fields) is for creating a new table.  There is another option called Append to Layer which sounds more like what you need however there seems to be an issue with this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39016